# OrderBy().FirstOrDefault(<condition>) vs. Where(<condition>).OrderBy().FirstOrDefault()

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Im using EntitiyFramework 6.1.3 with SQL Server in a C# Project.
I've two queries which basically should do the same.

1.

```
Exams.GroupBy(x=>x.SubjectID).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Level.NumericValue).FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today))
```

2.

```
Exams.GroupBy(x=>x.SubjectID).Select(x => x.Where(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today).OrderBy(y => y.Level.NumericValue).FirstOrDefault())
```

However, the result of the first query is the same as I would leave the order by away.
The second one works as expected.

When I look at the generated SQL via Linqpad there is no order by clause in the first query.

My question is, why does the first query not work like the second query?
I always thought

```
.Where(<condition>).FirstOrDefault() == .FirstOrDefault(<condition>)
```

like already answered here: [.Where(<condition>).FirstOrDefault() vs .FirstOrDefault(<condition>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842794/wherecondition-firstordefault-vs-firstordefaultcondition)

**EDIT:**
I played around a little more and I've found out that these two queries produce the same SQL output.

```
Exams.GroupBy(x => x.SubjectID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today))
Exams.GroupBy(x => x.SubjectID).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Level.NumericValue).FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today))
```

Even though it looks like a bug I'm still not 100% convinced.

Comment: Maybe you should react to the answers that have been posted. They have explained the issue, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the root cause of the problem, but there is a subtle difference between those two queries - the relative position of OrderBy and Where. In relational world, filter invalidates sorting done in the subquery. EF tries to compensate for this discrepancy by "lifiting" some of the orderbys after the filter, and perhaps is unable to lift this pattern properly. Try switching OrderBy and Where around in the second query:

```
Exams.GroupBy(x => x.SubjectID).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Level.NumericValue).Where(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today).FirstOrDefault())
```

and see if you still get the same generated SQL as unaltered version. If you do, it's definitely a bug in EF (I expect generated sql to be identical to query 1 and different than original query 2). Otherwise it may just be the limitation of the order by lifting algorithm.

In general, if you want to make it easier for EF - it is better to place your OrderBy-s after your Where-s.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the [related bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2521) was closed as being answered here on SO, this is clearly a bug. I ran into this exact same issue using a similar construction of an `OrderByDescending` followed by `FirstOrDefault` with predicate, within a `GroupBy`.

It appears that Entity Framework does not support a `FirstOrDefault` statement **with a predicate**, at least not in the context of this question. As the question states, the following expression yields a correct SQL query with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
Exams
    .GroupBy(x => x.SubjectID)
    .Select(x => x
        .Where(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today)
        .OrderBy(y => y.Level.NumericValue)
        .FirstOrDefault())
```

However, adding *any* predicate to the `FirstOrDefault` statement confuses EF and results in a **query without `ORDER BY`**:

```
Exams
    .GroupBy(x => x.SubjectID)
    .Select(x => x
        .Where(y => y.Date.Value > DateTime.Today)
        .OrderBy(y => y.Level.NumericValue)
        .FirstOrDefault(y => true)) // Tautology shouldn't have any effect, but it does!
```

The only way to work around this is splitting the `FirstOrDefault(predicate)` statement into `Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()`. Just make sure to add a comment to your code explaining this decision, because ReSharper correctly suggests using a single `FirstOrDefault(predicate)` statement. But doing so will bug your query!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on the LINQ provider, here EF. The specific patterns that a LINQ provider supports are rarely documented completely. I am not aware of any EF documentation on this issue. It is unclear whether this is a bug or whether it is supposed to work.

The LINQ technology itself is not able make any guarantees that this would always work.

I think this is supposed to work, or at least highly desirable that it works. Create a short Github issue pointing to this question. The team is very responsive.

For the time being you have no choice but to choose the pattern that works.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve call the ToList() method

Answer (score -1):

`.Where(<condition>).FirstOrDefault()` will return a IEnumerable list from your condition, then it gets the first or default value from that list. Where as the second `.FirstOrDefault(<condition>)` will apply the condition and get the first value that matches your condition. So the two will execute differently

Comment: All of this query stays in the IQueryable domain. IEnumerable is not a concern here.

Comment: Good point i didn't go read up up just spoke off the top of my head. IEnumerable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx does have a implementation for firstordefault though, the where is where my answer was lacking in this respect.